# GWT elemental2.dom.PushSubscription Missing keys (p256dh and auth) in PushSubscription

Tags: gwt, gwt-elemental

elemental2.dom.PushSubscription (v2.25, July 2019) has endpoint but not p256dh and auth keys, anyone know how to access these?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Phil.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but note that this is not included in elemental2 because it is a Firefox-only method (actually looks like it is already supported in [most browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/getKey#Browser_Compatibility), although [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/getKey#Specifications) said that it is Firefox-only).

```
{
    PushSubscription subscription = …;
    FirefoxPushSubscription firefoxPushSubscription = Js.cast(subscription);
}
@JsType(isNative = true, name = "PushSubscription", namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL)
public static class FirefoxPushSubscription extends PushSubscription {
    public native ArrayBuffer getKey(String name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked exactly as described. Not sure how best to convert the returned type ArrayBuffer to Java string, @Ignacio Baca is this something you have done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: but probably this key is not even a string, isn't it? you can represent it as a HEX string or if it is really a string you should decode it using https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String or https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/08/Easier-ArrayBuffer-String-conversion-with-the-Encoding-API

Comment: What I'd really like is to add a toJSON() to your FireFoxPushSubscription class which would return https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/toJSON - nothing I've tried works. Closest elemental native type I can find is JSONType. Otherwise I have call my own JS function which wraps the PushSubscription, this works but I wanted to avoid having the additional JS function.

Thanks in advance - @Ignacio Baca

Comment: Return an Object, you don't know the type so it is just an object. Then you can either create some type and cast to it or use the jsinterop.base.Js#asPropertyMap access each field.